# Why strcpy() copies every string to first index of 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, strcpy

I have a problem with filling a 2d char array with strings from a text file. I am trying to fill 2d array with specific strings from my file, but when I try to print out the first string at position 0 I get all strings connected as if they were one string. I tried it on more simple code and it worked where the strings were declared manually and weren't taken from a file. I've read something about the function itself but couldn't find anything which could couse a problem.

'''

```
char mer_mod[20], input_mer[20], input_mer_vel[20], data[25]; 
char line[20], time_arr[57][4];
double val_arr[57];
int flag = 0, offsets[5], n=1, j = 0, dates_arr[57], min_date, k =0;

if(strcmp(mer_mod, input_mer_vel) == 0 && flag == 1)  
{
    flag = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        memset(data,0,sizeof(data)); 
        fgets(data, sizeof data, *pp_file);   
                
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0: val_arr[k] = strtod(data, NULL); break;
            case 1: strcpy(time_arr[k], data); break;
            case 2: dates_arr[k] = atoi(data); break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", time_arr[0]);
    k++;
}
```

'''

When I print out string from the array at 0th index I get output from the first picture. In the second picture is output which I desire, but I get this output only if I'm printing the string right after it was added to the array.
time_arr is 2d char array, data is a character array where each line from the file gets stored.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a **complete** example.  What is `time_arr`?  What is `data`?

Comment: time_arr[57][] is  a 2d array where strings representing time in seconds and minutes should get stored. Data is character array where each line of file is stored when the program reads it.

Comment: @tadman that was the problem I thought that it will be something more complex and didnt think about the basics, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
 char time_arr[57][4];
```

Is an array of 57 elements of size 4

This

```
 data[25];
```

Is a string of 25 characters

So this

```
 strcpy(time_arr[k], data);
```

is wrong.  If data is longer than 3 characters (you have to leave space for the terminator) it will overrun the size of the array element.

> Note, based on the results it looks like you just do not have space for the null terminator -- it looks like `char time_arr[57][5];` would solve your problem

Comment: Thanks! Dont know why I haven't thought about that.